# Mysql подключается к localhost но не может к 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, linux, localhost, redhat

Подключаюсь как `root` к `mysql`, к `localhost`  подключается нормально, а к `127.0.0.1` - `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)` 
Вообще доступ необходим с другой машины этой локальной сети. Но для начала с этой же машины не получается.

пробовала и не помогло: 
- в `iptables` поставила по умолчанию все правила на `ACCEPT`
- убрала `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`  из конфига 
- рестартовала сервис

```
select host user from mysql.user:
    +-----------+------------------+
    | host      | user             |
    +-----------+------------------+
    | %         | root             |
    | localhost | debian-sys-maint |
    | localhost | mysql.session    |
    | localhost | mysql.sys        |
    | localhost | root             |
    +-----------+------------------+
```

Что необходимо настроить чтоб принимались подключения не только `localhost`?

Comment: Что выводит запрос `select host, user from mysql.user`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добваила в вопрос. Выводит что root  - % - со всех хостов?

Comment: Я ошибся в предыдущем комментарии (то есть он был правильный, но не по делу - поэтому удалён). Дело не в пользователе. Показанное сообщение действительно выдаётся именно клиентом, когда сервер не отвечает вообще (например, демон не запущен...). Смотрите, что блокирует подключение к локалхосту по адресу. Кстати, а если телнетом подёргать за сервер по соотв. порту по имени и по адресу - отклик одинаковый (пусть и непонятный) или разный?

Comment: @Akina у меня машина в облаке - redhat openstack platform, порты закрыты по умолчанию для telnet, как результат - ```telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
ubuntu@annotrack-human-db:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused```

mysql слушает на 3094  порту - он открыт

Comment: Да `%` обозначает любой хост

Comment: @AntonShchyrov верно, не подключается telnet  на этот порт, сейчас посмотрю настройки машины в облаке еще раз

Comment: Телнет не подключается, а mysql клиент на localhost подключается? Так не бывает. А у вас mysql на нестандартном порту. Я не заметил. Тогда на него же нужно цепляться и телнетом `telnet localhost 3094` и `telnet 127.0.0.1 3094`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, mysql цеплялось а telnet  - нет. Проблема и правда была в неверном порту,  mysql localhost  на неправильный порт цеплялось, а mysql 127.0.0.1 - нет. Спасибо за помощь, можете оформить как ответ - я приму

Comment: @Mira Оформляйте ответ сами :) Если репутации хватит, можете сделать его общим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильном порту, указанном при подключении. 
Если порт не правильный, к `localhost` `mysql` может соединится, а к `127.0.0.1` - нет